# Timeout error when saving large data in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am working in saving data from a zip file to Elasticsearch DB in a Python application, that zip file has HTML pages and domain names. Now I need to push data to array from that file and then need to save it in Elastic search DB.

The issue is that sometimes, when data is extensive because HTML can be of any size, then I get the error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=300)
```

ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=300))

I have tried increasing timeout value but I don't know how long can data become in future to save on update, so not sure what value should I put there.

Can anyone please help me in knowing that if this is the only way or is there any other better way to fix it.